# Is there any command line to show tree view directory?

Tags: command-line, ls, tree

Many tutorials depict tree-view directory to show how they organize their files. Is there any command line to show such view?

Is `ls` capable to do this?

Answer (score 24):

`Tree` is the command that will show you the `tree` view.

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

then just type `tree` from the terminal.  And `tree -d` will list only the directories and no files.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [tree](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/) command.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

[image]